# RequireJS use xhr to load scripts instead of <script> tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, requirejs, lazy-loading

i'm trying to lazy load Angular controller using `requirejs`

this is my code in resolve which is **working** as expected

```
require(['controllers/' + controllerName], function (data) {
    $stateParams.controllerName = data.name || controllerName;
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

but this method is adding `<script>` tag to `head` with requested url

i want to load this using `XHR` so that it will not add any script tags or display in resources.

i tried like this

```
require(['text!controllers/' + controllerName + '.js'], function (data) {
    var funcData = new Function(data)();  //expecting data as string
    $stateParams.controllerName = funcData.name || controllerName;
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

but im getting **error** since requirejs is trying to load `/text.js` instead of `/controllers/nameOfController.js`

is there a way to fix or any other better way to do this?
(i want to load scripts only with `XHR`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. finally this is what i figured out without breaking the actual functionality of `requirejs`. and now it uses `xhr` to load the scripts..

added this into `main.js` to override the original method.

**Note:** only use this in PROD otherwise will loose script debugging in browser.

```
require.load = function (context, moduleName, url) {
    var config = (context && context.config) || {},
        isBrowser = !!(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && window.document),
        isWebWorker = !isBrowser && typeof importScripts !== 'undefined',   
        makeError = function (id, msg, err, requireModules) {
            var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
            e.requireType = id;
            e.requireModules = requireModules;
            if (err) e.originalError = err;
            return e;
        },
        xmlhttp;
    if (isBrowser) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    try {
                        new Function(xmlhttp.responseText)();
                        context.completeLoad(moduleName);
                    } catch (e) {
                        context.onError(makeError('scripterror', 'executing script failed for ' + moduleName + ' at ' + url, e, [moduleName]));
                    }
                }
                else context.onError(makeError('notloaded', 'loading scripts failed for ' + moduleName + ' at ' + url, xmlhttp.status, [moduleName]));
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else if (isWebWorker) {
        try {
            importScripts(url);
            context.completeLoad(moduleName);
        } catch (e) {
            context.onError(makeError('importscripts', 'importScripts failed for ' + moduleName + ' at ' + url, e, [moduleName]));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [requirejs text](https://github.com/requirejs/text) dependency in your project?

Will look for `text.js` and will error if it doesn't exist.

Comment: i do.. but later i figured out that its looking in `basPath` instead of `bower-components` so i added actual path to `config.paths` and started working.. but its making `xhr` every time when i use the dependency instead of saving it in to modules.